# get query string into js/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i hae a link like ( domain.com/jsapi?key=123456 )

hov can i get this "key" into my JS code? i use jQuery and i don't know about its are easy way to get this "key" into JS variable.

tanks for all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This plugin might helps: [jquery url parser](http://projects.allmarkedup.com/jquery_url_parser/)

`key = $.url.setUrl($(yourlink).attr('href')).param('key');`

(not tested)

Answer (score 0):

It's not jquery. It's pure javascript. You can use regexp.

```
str = "domain.com/jsapi?key=123456" # Take it from wherever you want
splitted = str.split(/\?key=([0-9]+)/)
```

Then you'll have an array in the "splitted" variable, it's second element (at the id 1) containing the value.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery not needed. The query string is available from the DOM:

```
window.location.search.match(/key=([^&]*)/);
```

Which gives you an array that has your value in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the URL constructor as follows:

```
let url = new URL('https://example.com/jsapi?key=123456');
console.log(url.searchParams.get('key')); // Outputs 123456
```

Using this method you can parse and get any part of a URL.

Important:

- Note that I've added the protocol (https://) to the sample URL so I make sure it is a valid URL and it can be parsed.
- Take into account the browser compatibility. You can check it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL#Browser_compatibility)

For more details you can also the [the specification](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#constructors).